# How to add Today() in DojoDateTime in XPages

Tags: xpages

I would like to add today functions anywhere in this component which sets the field as Today. 
is it possible to do?

**COMPONENT CODE:**

```
<xp:inputText id="EvrakUlasimTarih" value="#{document1.EvrakUlasimTarih}"
                                            valueChangeListener="#{changeRequestBean.valueChangeListener}" dojoType="dijit/form/DateTextBox" styleClass="fs-12 datetimeStyle">
<xp:dateTimeHelper id="dateTimeHelper2"> </xp:dateTimeHelper>
<xp:this.converter>
<xp:convertDateTime type="date" dateStyle="short">
</xp:convertDateTime>
</xp:this.converter>
</xp:inputText>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component is open source, so yes, it's possible. I'm not aware of anyone who's extended the control to do that though. I suspect you would need to extend the renderer and add a function to jump to today's date in the JavaScript library incorporated by the renderer, but I may be over-simplifying it.

Answer (score 1):

Can you set the default value of the inputText to @Today()? May be this set the component to the current date

Comment: For example selected data is far far away(01.01.2001) and I need to change the date as Today. It should be a shortcut to click then field should be filled as Today by one click. otherwise I need to follow more steps chosing year, month and the day...

Did i explain well?